# Как приветствовать нового пользователя в тг канале (Pyrogram)

Tags: python, pyrogram, telegrambots

filters.new_chat_members пробовал, все равно не выходит

```
@app.on_message(filters=filters.new_chat_members)
async def hello(cl: client, msg: types.Message):
    print('New chat member')
```

Answer (score 0):

Из [официальной документации Pyrogram](https://docs.pyrogram.org/start/examples/welcome_bot):

```
from pyrogram import Client, emoji, filters

# Target chat. Can also be a list of multiple chat ids/usernames
TARGET = -100123456789
# Welcome message template
MESSAGE = "{} Welcome to [Pyrogram](https://docs.pyrogram.org/)'s group chat {}!"

app = Client("my_account")


# Filter in only new_chat_members updates generated in TARGET chat
@app.on_message(filters.chat(TARGET) & filters.new_chat_members)
async def welcome(client, message):
    # Build the new members list (with mentions) by using their first_name
    new_members = [u.mention for u in message.new_chat_members]
    # Build the welcome message by using an emoji and the list we built above
    text = MESSAGE.format(emoji.SPARKLES, ", ".join(new_members))
    # Send the welcome message, without the web page preview
    await message.reply_text(text, disable_web_page_preview=True)


app.run()  # Automatically start() and idle()
```